# How to get .eslintrc.js ignore all none js files

Tags: javascript, eslintrc

How to configure `.eslintr.js` to ignore all non-js files?

I started a `.eslintignore` file with the rule `!**/*.js` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. In the [.eslintignore section for negating (`!`)](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#eslintignore) (emphasis mine):

> Lines preceded by ! are negated patterns that **re-include a pattern that was ignored** by an earlier pattern.

So, ignore everything (you can use blob, or a specific directory, etc.) and then un-ignore js files:

```
src/
!src/**/*.js
```

Comment: That seems to ignore all `js` while I want the opposite.

Comment: @drum ahh sorry, I misunderstood you!